# How to check all the checkboxes in body when header is checked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Hi I have wpf application where in I have a datagrid with 3 check boxes in the header.

When any header checkbox is checked I want all the body checkboxes in that particular section to be checked.

Problem is when I check the header only the checkboxes that are visible in the view are checked. When I use the scroll bar and scroll down, the invisible checkboxes that are visible when scollbar is moved down, those check boxes are unchecked. Could anyone help. thanks. here is the code.

```
public IEnumerable<T> FindVisualChildren<T>(DependencyObject depObj) where T : DependencyObject
        {
            if (depObj != null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj); i++)
                {
                    var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
                    // If there is a child found and if the child is of the T type. 
                    //Dont remove null check . If no check i
                    if (child != null && child is T)
                    {
                        yield return (T)child;
                    }
                    foreach (T childOfChild in FindVisualChildren<T>(child))
                    {
                        yield return childOfChild;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
private void ChkHeaderExtract_OnChecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var extractCheckBoxes = GetAllCheckBoxs();
            var i = 0;
            foreach (var chk in extractCheckBoxes)
            {
                if (i % 3 == 0)
                {
                    chk.IsChecked = true;
                }
                i++;
            }

        }
```

XAML:

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="DgEntities" FrozenColumnCount="13" IsReadOnly="True" MaxWidth="854" Height="444" CanUserAddRows="false" ItemsSource="{Binding JobEntitiesCollectionViewSource.View, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionUnit="FullRow" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="21,-49,106,5" Width="763">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Entity" Width="220" MinWidth="172" MaxWidth="215"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="138" MaxWidth="138" MinWidth="138">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding ExtractStatus, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperlinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DgEntities}" Foreground="Blue" Cursor="Hand" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline"><InlineUIContainer>
                                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                                </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40" MaxWidth="40" MinWidth="40">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="ChkHeaderExtract" Checked="ChkHeaderExtract_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderExtract_OnUnchecked"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>

                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                            <DataTemplate>

                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Unchecked="ChkExtract_OnUnchecked" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="chkExtract" IsChecked="{Binding ExtractIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />

                            </DataTemplate>

                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>

                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="128" MaxWidth="128" MinWidth="128">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding TransformStatus, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperlinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DgEntities}" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="Blue" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick_2" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline"><InlineUIContainer>
                                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                                </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>
                                </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="40" MaxWidth="40" MinWidth="40">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="ChkHeaderTransform" Checked="ChkHeaderTransform_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderTransform_OnUnchecked"/>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>

                                <CheckBox HorizontalAlignment="Center" Unchecked="ChkTransform_OnUnchecked" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="chkTransform" IsChecked="{Binding TransformIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>

                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Status" Width="137.5" MaxWidth="137.5" MinWidth="137.5">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Button Margin="5" Content="{Binding LoadStatus, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" Command="{Binding DataContext.HyperlinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=DgEntities}" Cursor="Hand" Foreground="Blue" MouseDoubleClick="Control_OnMouseDoubleClick" >
                                    <Button.Template>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                                            <TextBlock TextDecorations="Underline"><InlineUIContainer>
                                                    <ContentPresenter />
                                                </InlineUIContainer></TextBlock>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Button.Template>

                                </Button>

                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Width="56" MaxWidth="56" MinWidth="56">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <CheckBox x:Name="ChkHeaderLoad" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0.3" Checked="ChkHeaderLoad_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkHeaderLoad_OnUnchecked" />
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <CheckBox Margin="8" x:Name="chkLoad" Checked="ChkLoad_OnChecked" Unchecked="ChkLoad_OnUnchecked" IsChecked="{Binding LoadIsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
```

Comment: You really should look in to using the MVVM pattern when dealing with WPF, it makes things like this SOOO much easier.  In MVVM, you would just bind your header checkbox to a property of the view model, then when the property it set to true just loop through your items and set their corresponding bound property to true.  All your UI is handled automatically; no need to go digging through the visual tree.

Comment: I have used MVVM and Prism. The collection view source property is coming from the ViewModel. I am using cs file only for code related to the view. Thats because for the body checkboxes, the properties are being bound from View Model. Hence I am using the cs file for IsChecked property and dont want to disturb any of the viewmodel bindings.

Comment: Hi Bradley I am trying to do it from View Model. Im binding the header checkbox property to viewmodel. What is the event that I need to raise in viewmodel when header checkbox is checked..Please help.

Comment: You shouldn't need the raise an event.  Just check to see if the value is true, if it is, loop though all the child objects you want to modify and set the property that their checkbox is bound to to True also.  The binding should take care of everything.

Comment: Hi Bradely I got it to work only problem that I face is, the Command property of the checkbox is not firing up. So just for test purposes Im taking a button and using the command parameter as checkbox. Do you have any idea how the command property of checkbox will fire up like a button. Thanks.

Comment: sorry, I don't.  I've never tried to bind a checkbox to a command.

Comment: If you use MVVM Light, you can bind any event to a command

Comment: Oh but I have been using Prism libraries. Let me check on MVVM light. Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

This will only return loaded children..

```
VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj)
```

you should update the actual bound object and then refresh the itemssource really.

Comment: Thanks that really makes sense the GetAllCheckBoxs() method is not returning unloaded children. Could you please write some sample code here so that it would be clear for me.

Comment: if I use LogicalTreeHelper will that solve my problem?